# could not load all results for selected value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to modify the items in listbox when it is databound.
suppose i have 1 listbox and 1 combobox.i want to display results in listbox only for the value selected in combobox and remove the other value in listbox in windows form in asp.net.

Comment: Do you mean DropDownList or ComboBox?

Comment: combobox and it works as a dropdownlist in windows form

Comment: @kirti show us code what you have tried

Comment: here, i have region in combobox and testcaseid in listbox. i only want to display testcaseid in the listbox for the region selected and does not want to show other testcaseid.it is basically a filter by region.

Comment: private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(con string);
           con.Open();
           String str = "select * from Table7 where Region='" + comboBox3.Text + "'";
           SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
           SqlDataReader  reader= com.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
               listBox1.SelectedValue= reader["Test_Case_ID"].ToString();
              
            }

            con.Close();
            reader.Close();}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add an OnSelectedIndexChanged to your combobox and set AutoPostBack="True"

Then selecting an item should trigger a post back and call the method you set for the OnSelectedIndexChanged. There you can fill the ListBox with values and remove the selected item from the ListBox too.